# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"И(,) если он их убил, не прощу ему этого" - нужна ли запятая перед "если"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В таком предложении запятая не нужна. "Запятая обычно не ставится между присоединительным союзом (после точки) и союзом подчинительным, например: И кто вы такой, я знаю; А зачем это говорится, мне непонятно". (Розенталь).

Comment: А можно ссылку на это правило?

Answer (score 0):

запятая не нужна. Если полное предложение таково, то нет запятой. А если в контексте есть мысль, например: "Я найду убийцу и, если он их убил, не прощу ему этого", тогда запятая ставится именно перед И.